# Selecionar ultimas conversas contando as mensagens não lidas em cada conversa

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, chat

Eu fiz um chat em NodeJS e já consigo trazer a lista de conversas. Porém, preciso trazer também a quantidade de mensagens não lidas de cada conversa.

Atualmente essa query traz o número total de mensagens não lidas em todas as conversas.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
            u.id AS uid,
            ch.sender_id,
            ch.notified,
            ch.receiver_id,
            u.name AS name,
            u.surname AS surname,
            ch.created_at,
            ch.message AS message,
            ch2.unread
        FROM chats ch
        NATURAL JOIN (
            SELECT
                SUM(IF(`read` = 0 , 1,0)) AS unread
            FROM     chats
            WHERE    receiver_id = 1
        ) ch2
        INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = 
            IF(ch.sender_id = 1,
               ch.receiver_id,
               ch.sender_id
            )
            WHERE ch.id IN(
                SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM(
                    SELECT id,
                        sender_id AS id_with
                    FROM chats
                    WHERE receiver_id = 1
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT id,
                        receiver_id AS id_with
                    FROM chats
                WHERE sender_id = 1) AS t
                GROUP BY id_with)
                ORDER BY ch.id DESC
```

Comment: E qual é o problema de colocar mais uma cláusula no WHERE?

Comment: A questão é: Onde colocar?